# Trying to print an int but it comes up with : TypeError must be str, not float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my program to print an int which follows a string. I'm not sure if that affects it or what but it comes up with the error whenever it tries to print.

I've tried using "," instead but I don't want to as it outputs `The Price Is £ 7.0` but it doesn't look as good as `£7.0`

```
price = 10
age = int(input("How Old Are You? - "))
if age > 12 and age < 14:
  price = price * 0.7

print("The Price Is £"+price)
```

Comment: `print("The Price Is £"+str(price))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because you have to concatenate you int :

```
print("The Price Is £"+str(price))
```

Answer (score 1):

`price` is a float, so it cannot be concatenated to a string. Use string formatting instead:

```
print(f"The Price Is {price}£")
```

For example:

```
>>> price = 0.7
>>> print(f"The Price Is {price}£")
The Price Is 0.7£
```

Comment: nitpick: `price` is actually a float, not an int :)

Comment: @JowanMckend you are welcome, please consider reading this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print("The Price Is {}£".format(price))
```

Or

```
print("The Price Is £",price)
```